# Write/Read Apache Parquet Files in Java/Spring

Tags: java, spring, maven, parquet

I'm just trying to write a parquet file, but every example I find on google uses deprecated methods or simply just doesn't work.
Besides, there doesn't seem to be any official documentation with examples.

It would be interesting to see a writting example and a reading-to-POJO example as well.

Comment: have a look here: https://github.com/apache/parquet-mr/blob/master/parquet-hadoop/src/main/java/org/apache/parquet/hadoop/ParquetWriter.java

Comment: thanks, but that is still using deprecated methods/Classes that will be removed in version 2.0.0